# strongly convergent operators applied to a weakly convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it true (and why?) or not (then how can it fail?) that if $T_n\to T$ in the operator strong topology on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $x_n\to x$ in the weak topology of $\mathcal{H}$ then $T_n x_n\to Tx$ weakly in $\mathcal{H}$? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $e_n$ be the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$, $T_n:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ defined by $T_n(x)=(n^{th} $ component of $x)$ $e_1$ and $x_n=e_n$. Then $T_n\to 0$ in the strong operator topology and $x_n\to 0$ weakly but $T_n(e_n)=e_1$ for all $n$.

Comment: So much clear, thanks! (I am to understand that you used $x_n$ both as the $n$-th component of the vector $x$ and as the vector of the weakly convergent sequence, but it is clear anyhow.) Thank you!

Comment: Fabulous. But you may want to rewrite this somehow - I honestly couldn't follow it until I saw the comment pointing out that you were using "$x_n$" to mean two different things...